# Making XML document in android

Tags: android, xml, namespaces, document

I have problem adding prefix to my XML document, I need every element to have tns prefix, but for some reason it doesn't work. Not understanding XML fully is also possibility :)

Code:

```
  serializer.startDocument(null, Boolean.valueOf(true)); 
  serializer.setPrefix("tns","http://some.web.addres");
  serializer.setPrefix("xsi", "http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance%22");
  serializer.startTag("tns","Something");

  serializer.startTag("tns", "Zaglavlje");


  serializer.attribute("tns", "blabla", "bla");
  serializer.startTag("tns", "otvaramtopic");
  serializer.text("imam neki tekst");
  serializer.endTag("tns", "otvaramtopic");
  serializer.startTag("tns", "sadrzaj");
  serializer.text("sadrzaj sadrzaja");
            // close tag: </content>
        serializer.endTag("tns", "sadrzaj");

            // open tag: <author>
            serializer.startTag("tns", "autor");
            serializer.text("tekst autoru");
            // close tag: </author>
            serializer.endTag("tns", "autor");

            // open tag: <date>
            serializer.startTag("tns", "novitag");
            serializer.text("nekeja");
            // close tag: </date>
            serializer.endTag("tns", "novitag");

            // close tag: </study>
            serializer.endTag("tns", "Zaglavlje");
            // close tag: </record>
            serializer.endTag("tns", "Something");


        serializer.endDocument();
```

And in the result prefix is n0. What to do to change prefix to tns?

Comment: kao na početku taga ili gore gdje definiram prefix? btw. zdravo :)

Comment: Ne bi trebali ovde na srpskom/hrvatskom ili sta vec al drago mi je sto imaljudi sa balkana :) did you call endDocument() ?

Comment: istina, al eto, kad si se vec javil moral sam :) I did, it's going to a xml file.

Comment: i just don't know how to achieve tns prefix.